# JNA Function call to C dll

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface

I need to call the c dll (mycppdll.dll) from my java application.

```
CFUNCTIONSDLLCALLS int PASCAL SomeFunction(
      char *param1, char *param2,
      char *param3, char *param4,
      char *param5,
      int  *param6,
      int  *param7,
      int  *param8);
```

I have a c program calling this function like this :

```
 char param1[256] = "";
 char param2[256] = "";
 char param3[256] = "";
 char param4[256] = "";
 char param5[256] = "";
 int param6;
 int param7;
 int param8[32];
ret = SomeFunction(param1,param2,param3,param4,param5, &param6, &param7, &param8[0]);
```

and it is perfectly working fine.

In my java program for char * i am using PointerByReference and int* as IntegerByReference.
I dont know what should i use for the last parameter.

I tried to pass Pointer of 0th index of the integer array, PointerByReference of Pointer of 0th index of the integer array, int , IntByReference.

None of them are working. I am getting

> "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'SomeFunction':
>   The specified procedure could not be found."

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It appears that SomeFunction is not part of the dll (or maybe it doesn't have the same arguments)